# CRON Job Error with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, cron-job, cron

with the help of another users i was able to get my CRON jobs to run however I seem to be getting a different error now:

```
Fatal error: Smarty error: [in string:&lt;meta content=&quot;text/html; charset=UTF-8&quot; http-equiv=&quot;Content-Type&quot; /&gt;
&lt;meta content=&quot;width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;&quot; name=&quot;viewport&quot; /&gt;
&lt;title&gt;&lt;/title&gt;
&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }

*{
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.ReadMsgBody
{width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
.ExternalClass
{width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
body{width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; margin:0; padding:0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
html{width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima_novalight';src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/template/templates/titan/font/proximanova-light-webfont.eot');src: url('http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/template/templates/titan/font/proximanova-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-ope in /home/promedic/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1094
<!-- deferred 0 scripts, deferred 0 styles & minified html in 1 seconds -->
```

My cron jobs looks like this, and seems to be running ok if i am to believe the run times in the scheduled jobs page

```
/usr/bin/wp --user=USERNAME --url=https://URL --path=/home/promedic/public_html --timezone="Pacific/Efate" civicrm api job.execute auth=0
```

I am running Civi 4.6.14 on WordPress 4.7.2

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before.  Cron will fail while processing mailings (any type) if a smarty error occurs.  I would review the templates being used.